# Bash script is not working as cron job

Tags: linux, unix, bash, cron

I have the following shell script

```
$cat capture.sh 
TIME=$(date +"%H-%M-%d-%m-%y") 
IP="203.208.198.29" 
PREFIX=$TIME$IP 
tshark  -f "udp" -i eth0 -w /root/captures/$PREFIX.cap& 
pid=$! 
sleep 2m 
kill $pid
```

it runs fine when i execute it from shell.

but when i add it to the cron tab nothing happens.

my crontab entry : 
    1 */2 * 2 3,4,5 sh /root/capture.sh

```
tail /var/log/cron
```

shows that the command has executed .

but nothing happens. i have set executable permission for "all" for capture.sh and write permission for "all" for /root/captures directory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you drop the cron job shell script into the cron.hourly directory? Will it run that way? (note: make it executable)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your `PATH` variable probably isn't what you expect it to be inside cron.

Use full paths to each executable in your script or set the path manually in your crontab or the script.

Also, a better way of stopping your `tshark` would be using the built-in functionality:

```
   -a  <capture autostop condition>
       duration:value Stop writing to a capture file after value seconds
       have elapsed.
```

Also #2: add a shebang line (`#!`)

Comment: What is this...I don't even...

Comment: environment variable is supported in cron.                         man 5 crontab 
       An  active line in a crontab will be either an environment setting or a cron command.  An environ-
       ment setting is of the form,
         name = value

Answer (score 3):

Cron will limit the path used by cron jobs. Try /usr/sbin/tshark instead of just tshark. You can check where tshark is via `which tshark`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your script I see you're attempting to capture traffic for two minutes and write a file.  Did you really mean to have a cronjob that runs on every Wed/Thur/Friday in February, every other hour at 1 past the hour?  I'm guessing you wanted it to run every 2 minutes...

From `crontab(5)` (which can be read with `man 5 crontab`)

```
   cron(8) examines cron entries once every minute.

   The time and date fields are:

          field          allowed values
          -----          --------------
          minute         0-59
          hour           0-23
          day of month   1-31
          month          1-12 (or names, see below)
          day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)

   A field may be an asterisk (*), which always stands for "first-last".
```

Comment: no i'm trying to run it in every two hours. I'm doing some data mining  to find a pattern. so i'm taking a sample every two hours.

Comment: Then you want to do 0 */2 * * *

Answer (score 0):

It because tshark command was not found, you have two options to fix it.

1. define path in crontab

   PATH=$PATH:/path-to-tshark

   */2 * 2 3,4,5 sh /root/capture.sh
2. Use full path of tshark in your script.

   option #1 is the preferred way